# Is it acceptable to allow people to post Q&A style questions linking to external sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, self-answer, link-only-answers

As a specific example I'm thinking this which I came across:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670702/simple-way-to-develop-a-mobile-app-in-html5-using-phonegap/15723852#15723852

Ok it seems pretty uneventful but if I was doing some dodgy SEO to my tech blog, couldn't I post lots of these all over SO and thus direct traffic towards my site?

My points on this are:

- The answer in itself isn't really an answer as it simply contains a
  link.
- No one's really asked for it, it's a Q&A style (or he's answered his own question)

I get the feeling if I flagged it, it'd just get rejected? Should anything be done with this or am I getting a bit overexcited?!

Comment: [Link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259).

Comment: Self-answering is ok, but doing it this way is not ... I agree, this is simply link-farming.

Comment: So this should be flagged. Ok, cool.

Comment: One thing I would say, if I was link link-farming, if my answer isn't deleted then, I've succeeded, no? Getting downvotes, etc. don't really have an impact, it's prob not my account anyway!